# If the intersection of the preimage of a generic point of a flat morphism with an open set is dense, does it imply the open set is dense?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

> Let $f: E \rightarrow M $ be a flat morphism of varieties (over $\mathbb{C}$)
>   and $E^{\prime}$ an open subset of $E$. Assume that both $E$ and $E^{\prime}$ 
>   have pure dimension $2n$, where $n$ is the dimension of $M$. Suppose that for a generic point $p \in M$, the set $f^{-1}(p) \cap E^{\prime} $ is open and dense in $E^{\prime}$. Does it imply that $E^{\prime}$ is dense in $E$?

PS: I don't know if this fact is relevant, but I believe that since $f$ is flat, every irreducible component of $E$ dominates $M$ (but I am not sure if this statement is true). I believe dominate means the image is dense in $M$.

Comment: No: for example if M is a point, then your hypothesis on the fibre doesn't give any extra information, but E might have several components.

Comment: Thank you. In the specific example I have, the dimension of $E$ is twice that the dimension of $M$. I have edited the question. Is the answer still no?

Comment: The answer is still no: think about how one could modify my trivial example to achieve any relative dimension you like.

Comment: @ YACP: Sorry, I have removed that tag.

Comment: To be more precise, above I meant "any combination of dimensions" rather than "any relative dimension".